# Two display monitors instead of built-in display

Tags: 14.04, display

I have two monitors and my laptop's built-in display. However, my laptop has only a 15 inch screen, so **I would like to use my two monitors instead of one monitor and my built-in display.**

I have connected both my monitors to my laptop's docking station, and **they also display the desktop screen when I turn them on.** The problem is, even though the two monitors display the desktop screen, **I am only able to use one of them (i.e the mouse pointer does not extend to one of the screens).** It is still one monitor and my built-in display.

If it is possible to use all the three screens, well and good. If not, **how to turn off my built-in display and use my two monitors?**

Answer (score 0):

Been there.  Done that.  Still have dust on the lid of the laptop.  I don't know if what worked for me will necessarily work for you, but it probably will if your laptop is configured similarly.

AFTER MUCH fiddling with NVIDIA drivers and configuration screens, I discovered that my HP DV9000 laptop which I was initially given as a basket case broken laptop, was actually supposed to come with an IR wireless remote. I was able to purchase it on eBay which permitted me to turn it on while leaving the lid shut.  Unsurprisingly, HP designed these laptops to not power up their display when the lid is shut.

Providing yours is similarly configured, you may be able to do this.  Alternatively, you may be able to configure your power settings to not put the laptop to sleep when the lid is shut, and it is possible that the internal screen will power down with the lid closed.

Comment: no it doesn't seem to work. I have an HP too.. But when I close the lid, the two monitors still display, but I am only able to use one of them.

Comment: I may have a solution for you.  If I recall correctly, my installation worked perfectly until I upgraded from the NVIDIA 304 driver to something else, the 319?  In any case, that wasted weeks while I figured out how to put it back.  Finally I stopped using that laptop altogether, but for a time it was necessary to use exactly one NVIDIA package which worked better than all others.  I won't assume your HP is as old, or as abused, as mine, but you may have to try a few drivers before you find the one that works best.